# How to shorten the length of underline by reducing 30px from both ends in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to add an underline under my h1 heading and make it just a little short then the heading itself. 30px space should remove from both ends. how to fix this?

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

```
h1 {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

One way to do it is with ::after element. Use left to shift it for 30px.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you want to do if the heading is long and overflows to another (shorter) line, but assuming you literally want just a border shortened by 60px then you can add a before pseudo element of the same height but less width.

```css
h1 {
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  --indent: 30px;
}

h1::before {
  width: calc(100% - (2 * var(--indent)));
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: var(--indent);
  ;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

This snippet defines a variable with the indent required (30px) so it will be easy for you to change it if required.

Answer (score 0):

You may fake the underline via a background and shorten it via background-size:

here is an example of the idea:

```css
h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000000 0 2px, transparent 2px) 50% 0 / calc(100% - 60px) 100% no-repeat;
  width: fit-content;
}

h2 {
  color: green;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, currentColor 0 2px, transparent 2px) 50% 0 / calc(100% - 60px) 100% no-repeat;
  width: fit-content;
}

h2+h2 {
  color: tomato;
  line-height: 0.95em;
  transition:0.25s
}
h2 + h2:hover {line-height:1.6em;}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>

<p>extras for infos</p>
<h2>Match colors via currentColor</h2>
<h2>move that fake underline closer or further away</h2>
```